# How to fold C code with vim?

Tags: c, vim, folding

I've been trying to explore code folding options in Vim, and I have stumbled upon this stack-overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851916/compact-c-folding-in-vim). While I have been able to put that into my `vimrc`, the problem I'm having is that **it doesn't fold the multi-line comments above a function**. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default `syntax/c.vim` provides folding definitions. Unless you define a `c_no_comment_fold` variable, this also folds multi-line comments.

To activate this, just put

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`.